# What is windows equivalent to finding ancestor of file?

Tags: git

I'm following the guided tour by [Git Immersion](http://gitimmersion.com/) and lab 13 tells me:

> Let’s tag the version immediately prior to the current version v1-beta. First we need to checkout the previous version. Rather than lookup up the hash, we will use the ^ notation to indicate “the parent of v1”.
>
> If the v1^ notation gives you any trouble, you can also try v1~1, which will reference the same version. This notation means “the first ancestor of v1”.

After successfully tagging my current file as `v1`, I try

```
git checkout v1^
```

as well as

```
git checkout v1~1
```

and I get

```
> pathspec 'v1^' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

and

```
> pathspec 'v1~1' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Is this failing because I'm using Windows (even through I'm using the bash shell)?

Comment: Your error message says `vi` (vee eye) but the rest says `v1` (vee one).  Could that be the problem?

Comment: the typo has been fixed (I definitely typed the git commands correctly)

Comment: OK.  I avoid windows so don't know about windows-bash, but there's still something weird here as even if there's no `v1` tag the error message should complain about `v1^` and `v1~` respectively.  (But with the tag present git should resolve plain `v1` to the tag anyway!)

Comment: This probably indicates that you missed a step earlier in the assignment that would have dropped a tag named `v1` somewhere. Either that or your branch was supposed to be named `v1` and you chose to give it a different name. Check the output of `git tag` and `git branch` to make sure that either a tag or branch named `v1` exists, and if not, figure out where it's supposed to be and create it...

Comment: the error messages complain just as you would expect

Comment: after I typed git tag v1, I got the nice green and yellow line saying /e/Dropbox/gitimmersion/git_tutorial/work/hello ((v1)).    That ((v1)) means I successfully tagged the branch, right?

Comment: git tag gives me "v1".................git branch gives me "master"